# Drupal sign up code

Tags: hooks, users

If a user does not have a Sign Up code they can enter the email address in which case they enter a user processing status. A user in this process with receive 4 pre-written emails as below

1. Email Template 1 sent after 1 day
2. Email Template 2 sent after 3 days
3. Email Template 3 sent after 5 days containing a sign up code
4. Email Template 4 sent after 10 days only if eMail Address has not joined

In drupal how we can do this functionality?
is there module for this?

Answer (score 2):

You can set up an e-mail scheduling workflow with the [rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) module.  You can watch a screencast on how to set up rules scheduling [here](http://dev.nodeone.se/node/654).

EDIT: If you are completely new to rules, the Node One screencast [starts here](http://dev.nodeone.se/node/634).

Comment: I am new to drupal having no idea how to use Rule.Can you please give me some detail description...

Comment: I also need help for : Only users with a "Sign Up Code" are allowed to sign up to the website. If they provide a valid signup code, they will be directed to a sign up page where they can provide user information, and PayPal processing is used to process the fee. On completion of payment an account is created.

How can I redirect user to Paypal?
How can I check the payment is paid by user?
How can I create the account if the user paid?

Comment: You will have to generate the sign up code somehow.  I don't know of a system in Drupal that can do that.  I updated my answer with where to get started on learning the rules module.  As for your other questions, please see the guidelines for using this site.  1. One question per post. 2. If a book could answer your question, you need to narrow it down more.